# "Error code [1046]; No database selected;" while executing DDL using jdbcTemplate from Spring boot app

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, debezium

I created a database replicator (MySQL) application (Spring boot) using Debezium. Debezium listens to any SQL running in the source database by reading binlogs. As the application receives all the DDLs and DMLs from the debezium connector, it executes them on the target database. MySQL doesn't store DDLs in the binlog in their original format. They are converted from below SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE A.B;
into
USE A;
CREATE TABLE B;
```

i.e. it converts it into 2 statements. But when I run these statements separately on the target database:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("USE A");
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE B");
```

it gives me

```
SQL state [3D000]; error code [1046]; No database selected;
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

Note: I didn't want to include the schema name in my JDBC [URL = `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308`] for the target database as I can receive drop database commands too.

How can I possibly solve this?

Edit: I would want to avoid modifying the DDL to include a database qualifier.

Comment: If you "USE" you "use database-name" then you create tables in the database "with" columns "with" assigned "data types" for the data that will be placed in the column row. See your db manual and Google some tutorials for your db type.

Comment: I guess I can use a clearer explanation

Comment: Yup, it's called a tutorial and manual for your database and version!

Comment: Very unhelpful. But thanks!

Comment: This tutorial site is good for beginners.  https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_create_db.asp

Comment: Well, I don't have any tutorial suggestions for you on how read and understand a question

Comment: You got a point there. It is better now to read if not exists , if exists. AFAIK any JDBC connection must have a dbname in it's url.